# how can i find this query in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

For each student, find the number of courses they take and sort
the rows in descending order. (e.g. student id, the number of
courses taken by that student)

```
STUDENT TABLE

| ID      | name      | dept_name      | tot_cred |
| S0901   | Alice     | Comp.Sci.      | 83       |
| S0902   | Martha    | Comp.Sci.      | 75       |
| S0903   | Micheal   | Comp.Sci.      | 45       |
| S0904   | Rose      | Comp.Sci.      | 77       |
| S0905   | Alfie     | Comp.Sci.      | 91       |
| S1901   | Brad      | Biology        | 23       |

TAKES TABLE

| ID      | course_id      | sec_id      | semester      | year      | grade      
| S0901   | CS-101         | 1           | Fall          | 2009      | A          
| S0901   | CS-315         | 1           | Spring        | 2010      | B+         
| S0901   | HIS-351        | 1           | Spring        | 2010      | A-         
| S0901   | MTH-101        | 1           | Fall          | 2009      | A          
| S0901   | MTH-102        | 1           | Spring        | 2009      | B+   
| S0902   | CS-101         | 1           | Fall          | 2009      | A          
| S0902   | CS-315         | 1           | Spring        | 2010      | B+         
| S0902   | CS-319         | 1           | Spring        | 2010      | B          
| S0902   | HIS-351        | 1           | Spring        | 2010      | A-         
| S0902   | MTH-101        | 1           | Fall          | 2009      | A          
| S0902   | MTH-102        | 1           | Spring        | 2009      | B+         
| S1901   | CS-101         | 1           | Fall          | 2009      | B+         
| S1901   | CS-190         | 1           | Spring        | 2009      | C          
| S1901   | CS-315         | 1           | Spring        | 2010      | A-         
| S1901   | HIS-351        | 1           | Spring        | 2010      | A-
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, @Marcinek's answer may not be sufficient because it omits students who take zero classes. I would use this instead:

```
SELECT STUDENT.ID, COUNT(TAKES.ID)
FROM STUDENT LEFT JOIN TAKES ON STUDENT.ID = TAKES.ID
GROUP BY STUDENT.ID
ORDER BY COUNT(TAKES.ID) DESC;
```

By using `LEFT JOIN`, you can capture a student whose ID does not appear in the TAKES table.

Answer (score 0):

Just join and group up the result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), s.id FROM student s, takes t where t.id = s.id group by s.id order by count(*) desc
```